# Not able to remove loadable module

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

I am trying to learn about Linux device drivers. I am trying to install the module using [insmod](https://www.netadmintools.com/html/insmod.man.html) from the command line. After insertion, I try to remove the loaded module, which fails with the error,

> `could not remove module hello: Device or resource busy`

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251822/not-able-to-remove-a-loadable-kernel-module) but it doesn't seem to provide a valid answer.

Below is the C code (`hello.c`) of the module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>     /* Needed for the macros */

static int data __initdata = 3;

#ifdef USE_OLDER_NAMING

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    return -1;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}

#else

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello Module Inserted : %d \n",data);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello Module removed : %d \n",data);
    return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

#endif
```

I am compiling this module with the following Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

After compiling, I install the module using the command `sudo insmod ./hello.ko`. I can see the loaded module in `/proc/modules`.
Output of `cat /proc/modules | grep hello` is `hello 12490 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (POF)`.

When I check in `dmesg`, I can see the logs `Hello Module Inserted : 3`. When I try to remove the module, I am getting the below error

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'hello': Device or resource busy
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module hello: Device or resource busy
```

Output of `cat /proc/modules | grep hello` is `hello 12422 0 - Unloading 0x0000000000000000 (POF-)`

My question is how to remove that module? And what is wrong with sequence/code?

Comment: What platform/kernel?

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic

Comment: Can you replicate problem with newer 4.x/5.x kernels?
Here similar problem got fixed:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/not-able-to-remove-loadable-kernel-module-lkm-using-rmmod-4175495472/#post5120673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , there is a return statement in your **my_exit** function which is causing this problem.

And as for unloading part, if you want to forcefully remove a module then you have to enable **CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD** in the kernel. Otherwise, you have to restart your system.